# Modify Form Submission string

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to limit the values that get passed within my form. So for example:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input name="check1" type="radio" value="123" checked>
    <input name="check2" type="radio" value="456" checked>
    <input name="check3" type="radio" value="789" checked>
    <input type="submit" title="submit" id="btn_submit">
</form>
```

Now if I goto submit that I get something like below for the url

> www.domain.com/?check1=123&check2=456&check3=789

How can I control that to send just 'check3'? So the url would be

> www.domain.com/?check3=789

Comment: So even if the user clicks on check1, you don't want it included in the submission? Then why is it in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your radio buttons should share the same name. Give them unique IDs if you need to identify them with JS.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input name="check3" type="radio" value="123" checked>
    <input name="check3" type="radio" value="456" checked>
    <input name="check3" type="radio" value="789" checked>
    <input type="submit" title="submit" id="btn_submit">
</form>
```

If that's not what you want, only include the input fields in the form if you want them to be included in the submission.

Comment: So lets take the case of if I have a radio button that populates a drop down list. How would I just pass the value of the drop down list?

Comment: Take the radio button out of the form.

Comment: @Barmar But that radio button is the interaction to populate the drop down.

Comment: So? I didn't say to get rid of it, just move it outside the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="check1" type="radio" value="123" checked>
<input name="check2" type="radio" value="456" checked>
<input name="check3" type="radio" value="789" checked>

<form action="" method="get">
    ... other form elements
    <input type="submit" title="submit" id="btn_submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How is this the answer? This will not post any of the radio buttons as requested in the question!

Comment: I surmised from his later comments that he doesn't actually care about submitting that radio button. See his comments below where he says that the radio button is used to populate a drop down list. I presume that's done by some Javascript he didn't show us.